# How to use NSString getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, character-encoding, nsstring

I have a string that I want as a byte array.  So far I have used NSData to do this:

```
NSString *message = @"testing";
NSData *messageData = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSUInteger dataLength = [messageData length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc( dataLength );
memcpy( byteData, [messageData bytes], dataLength );
```

But, I know that NSString has the `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:` method that would allow me to skip using NSData all together.  My issue is, I don't know how to properly set all the parameters.

I assume the pointer array passed in has to be malloc'ed - but I'm not sure how to find how much memory to malloc.  I know there is `[NSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:]` and `[NSString maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:]` but I don't know if those are the methods I need to use and don't fully understand the difference between them.  I assume this would be the same value given to `maxLength`.  The rest of the parameters make sense from the documentation.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:` and `maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:` is that the former is exact but slow (O(n)) while the latter is fast (O(1)) but may return a considerably larger number of bytes than is actually needed. The only guarantee that `maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:` gives is that the return value will be large enough to contain the string's bytes.

Generally, your assumptions are correct. So the method should be used like this:

```
NSUInteger numberOfBytes = [message lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
void *buffer = malloc(numberOfBytes);
NSUInteger usedLength = 0;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [message length]);
BOOL result = [message getBytes:buffer maxLength:numberOfBytes usedLength:&usedLength encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding options:0 range:range remainingRange:NULL];
...
free(buffer);
```